# HTML & CSS: Embedded Video with overlayed Nav Bar based on Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, iframe

So I have this Video I want to present on my Website which is already built. I want to change things up by placing the video full screen on the landing page as you load up the website. Then, scrolling down, the video should always stay full screen but the nav bar, logo and a few text elements should overlay the video (with a fade in based on scroll position), pausing the video at a certain point. After everything fully faded in, I want the video to scroll down with everything on top as it would if it were an image.

I have absolutely no Idea what css elements to use for this and I am looking for some hints and ideas of how to build this. I didn't find any websites that had this as an example but I am sure everyone has seem something of this kind. Also, this would be difficult to implement as a mobile version...

Sorry for not including code, just doesn't make sense in this case. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried some basics - for example putting a video element autoplaying (it will have to be muted for some OS at least) on your landing page. Also have you tried layering the text and so on to be on top (e.g. z-index) and have you looked into sticky - I'm not sure whether this is relevant for your navbar and so on but it might be.

Comment: I will look into that, thanks!